# How to register / unregister for protocol at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a proper way to unregister and register view controller to protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To formally conform to a protocol:

```
class_addProtocol([MyViewController class], @protocol(SomeProtocol));
```

Even more dynamically:

```
class_addProtocol(objc_getClass("MyViewController"), objc_getProtocol("SomeProtocol"));
```

To actually add method implementations to a class:

```
// - (int)someMethod:(int)arg;
int someMethod(id self, SEL _cmd, int arg)
{
    return arg * 2;
}

class_addMethod([MyViewController class], @selector(someMethod:), (IMP)someMethod, "i@:i");
```

Beware the method signature (4th argument to `class_addMethod()`) in this case, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Objective-C Runtime method

```
BOOL class_addProtocol(Class cls, Protocol *protocol)
```

in order to add a protocol to a class at runtime, but as far as I know you cannot remove it.